geometry of two planes in $\mathbb{R}^4$
Problem: classify pairs of trivially intersecting 2-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^4$, up to orthogonal transformations.
Linear algebra solution: if $(U, V)$ is such a pair, consider the orthogonal projection to $V$ operator, proj$_V: \mathbb{R}^4\to V$. Restrict it to $P: U\to V$. We claim the singular values of $P$ form a complete invariant for $(U,V)$ under the action of $O(4)$.
Invariance is clear because $P$ is defined without coordinates. Conversely, if $P_{UV}$ and $P_{U'V'}$ have the same singular values $\sigma_1 \geq \sigma_2 \geq 0$, then by the Singular Value Theorem we can find orthonormal bases $a_1, a_2$ of $U$ and $b_1, b_2$ of $V$ (resp $a_1', a_2'$ of $U'$ and $b_1', b_2'$ of $V'$) such that
$$P_{UV}(a_i) = \sigma_i b_i$$
$$P_{U'V'}(a_i') = \sigma_i b_i'.$$
Since $U \cap V = \{0\}$, $\{a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$, we can define a transformation $\mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ by adding primes.
We have $a_i \cdot b_j = \delta_{ij}\sigma_i$ because we know $P(a_i) = (a_i \cdot b_1 )b_1 + (a_i \cdot b_2)b_2 = \sigma_i b_i$. Similarly $a_i \cdot b_j  = \delta_{ij}\sigma_i$. Together with the fact that $a_i \cdot a_j = \delta_{ij} = a_i' \cdot a_j'$ and same for $b$'s, this shows the transformation is in fact orthogonal. $\qed$
Question: what's a solution in terms of quaternions?
By intersecting with the unit 3-sphere, problem is equivalent to classifying pairs of skew geodesics in $S^3$ up to isometry. Quaternionic multiplication should act by isometries. Can I say that there's a unique unit quaternion that multiples one geodesic to the other, and let the two parameters be its "arguments"?
This idea would work for skew lines in $\mathbb{R}^3$: there's a unique translation $ \circ $ rotation that takes one line to the other.

What do you mean by "trivially intersecting" ? With an intersection reduced to ${0}$ ?

Yes, that's what I mean

$
\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}
\newcommand\form[1]{\langle#1\rangle}
\newcommand\Form[1]{\Bigl\langle#1\Bigr\rangle}
\newcommand\rev\widetilde
$This is impossible. More specifically, the action of quaternion multiplication is not transitive on planes, nor is it transitive when restricted to intersecting planes, nor when restricted to trivially-intersecting planes.
My claim is that there is no unit quaternion $r$ such that the span of $r, rj$ is the span of $1, i$; nor such that the span of $r\frac{i+j}{\sqrt 2}, rk$ is the span of $1, i$.
In the first case we need
$$
  \alpha + \beta i = r,\quad \alpha' + \beta' i = rj.
$$
But the second equation becomes $-\alpha'j - \beta' k = r$ which contradicts the first.
In the second case we need
$$
  \alpha + \beta i = r\frac{i+j}{\sqrt 2},\quad \alpha' + \beta' i = rk.
$$
The second equation gives
$$
  r = \beta' j - \alpha'k
$$
implying also that $(\beta')^2 + (\alpha')^2 = 1$. Substituting this into the first equation yields
$$
  \alpha + \beta i = \frac1{\sqrt2}(-\beta' + \alpha' i + \alpha'j - \beta'k),
$$
thus
$$
  \sqrt2\alpha = -\beta',\quad \sqrt2\beta = \alpha',\quad \alpha' = \beta' = 0
$$
which is absurd.

The following is a framework for exploring this problem using geometric algebra, and is how I originally arrived at the above counterexamples.
We work in the Euclidean geometric algebra generated by the standard orthonormal basis $e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4$. Let $V_1 = \{e_1\}^\perp$ and let $I = e_1e_2e_3e_4$. We consider quaternions as rotors for $V_1$, i.e.
$$
  \alpha + \beta i + \gamma j + \delta k,\quad i = e_4e_3,\quad j = e_2e_4,\quad k = e_3e_2.
$$
The map from quaternions to $\R^4$ can easily be written
$$
  q \mapsto e_1\bigl(\form q_0 + \form q_2I\bigr)
$$
with $\form\cdot_k$ grade projection, and can be easily inverted to
$$
  v \mapsto \frac12(e_1v + \rev{e_1v}) + \frac12(e_1v - \rev{e_1v})I = e_1\cdot v + (e_1\wedge v)I
$$
where $X \mapsto \rev X$ is reversal.
We now see how two quaternions $q, q'$ form a bivector blade:
$$\begin{aligned}
  [q, q']
  &:= \Bigl[e_1\bigl(\form q_0 + \form q_2I\bigr)\Bigr]\wedge\Bigl[e_1\bigl(\form{q'}_0 + \form{q'}_2I\bigr)\Bigr]
\\&= \Form{e_1\bigl(\form q_0 + \form q_2I\bigr)e_1\bigl(\form{q'}_0 + \form{q'}_2I\bigr)}
\\&= \Form{\bigl(\form q_0 - \form q_2I\bigr)\bigl(\form{q'}_0 + \form{q'}_2I\bigr)}
\\&= [\form q_0\form{q'}_2 - \form{q'}_0\form q_2]I + \form{\form q_2\form{q'}_2}_2
\\&= \form{\rev q\wedge q'}_2I + \rev q\times q'.
\end{aligned}\tag1$$
The symbol $\times$ is the commutator product $X\times Y = \frac12(XY - YX)$. The expression $\form{\rev q\wedge q'}_2$ comes from noting that $\form{\rev q}_2\wedge\form{q'}_2 = 0$ because both are bivectors of the 3D subspace $V_1$. Both (1) and the following form of $[q, q']$ will be needed. Note that for any two quaternions $qq' = q\wedge q' + q\times q'$ with the former the symmetric part and the latter the antisymmetric part. Then
$$\begin{aligned}
  [q, q']
  &= \form{\rev q\wedge q'}_2I + \rev q\times q'
\\&= \frac12[\form{\rev qq'}_2 + \form{q'\rev q}_2]I + \frac12[\form{\rev qq'}_2 - \form{q'\rev q}_2]
\\&= \form{\rev qq'}_2\frac{I+1}2 + \form{q'\rev q}_2\frac{I-1}2.
\end{aligned}\tag2$$
In this form the action of a unit quaternion $r$ on a bivector blade is quite stark:
$$\begin{aligned}
  [rq, rq']
  &= \form{\rev{rq}rq'}_2\frac{I+1}2 + \form{rq'\rev{rq}}_2\frac{I-1}2
\\&= \form{\rev qq'}_2\frac{I+1}2 + r\form{q'\rev q}_2\rev r\frac{I-1}2.
\end{aligned}\tag3$$
We will be interested in the magnitude $[q,q']$. Since it is a blade we simply compute its square using (1):
$$
  [q,q']^2 = \form{\rev q\wedge q'}_2^2 + (\rev q\times q')^2 + \Bigl[\form{\rev q\wedge q'}_2(\rev q\times q') + (\rev q\times q')\form{\rev q\wedge q'}_2\Bigr]I.
$$
Because the result has to be scalar, the coefficient of $I$ must have grade 4; but all the involved quantities live in the 3D subspace $V_1$ so this coefficient must be zero. Thus
$$
  [q,q']^2 = \form{\rev q\wedge q'}_2^2 + (\rev q\times q')^2.
\tag4
$$
Finally, note that because $e_1$ is orthogonal to $V_1$ we have the $e_1$ commutes with any $V_1$ bivectors; note also that $e_1$ anticommutes with $I$. It follows that
$$
  \frac12([q,q'] - e_1[q,q']e_1) = \form{\rev q\wedge q'}_2,\quad
  \frac12([q,q'] + e_1[q,q']e_1) = \rev q\times q'.
\tag5$$
Finally, the desired theorem may be stated as follows:

For any quaternions $q, q', p, p'$ such that $[q,q']^2 = [p,p']^2$, there exists a unit quaternion $r$ such that $[q,q'] = \pm[rp,rp']$.

Using (3) and (5), we get that $[q,q'] = \pm[rp,rp']$ is equivalent to
$$
  {\pm2}\form{\rev q\wedge q'}_2 = \form{\rev pp'}_2 + r\form{p'\rev p}_2\rev r
  \quad\text{and}\quad
  {\pm2}\rev q\times q' = \form{\rev pp'}_2 - r\form{p'\rev p}_2\rev r.
\tag6
$$
But now choose $q = 1, q' = i$ and $p = 1, p' = j$ while noting that $[1,i]^2 = [1,j]^2$. Then by (6) we need
$$
  \pm2i = j + rj\rev r,\quad j = rj\rev r,
$$
but substituting the second into the first leads to $\pm i = j$, which is absurd. So there is no $r$ taking the plane $[1, i]$ to the plane $[1, j]$.
The action isn't even transitive on trivially intersecting planes; consider $[1, i]$ and $[\frac{i+j}{\sqrt2}, k]$ which have the requisite magnitudes $[1,i]^2 = [\frac{i+j}{\sqrt2},k]^2$. Then by (6) we need
$$
  \pm2i = \frac{j-i}{\sqrt2} - r\frac{j-i}{\sqrt2}\rev r,\quad 0 = \frac{j-i}{\sqrt2} + r\frac{j-i}{\sqrt2}\rev r.
$$
Together these imply
$$
  \pm i = \frac{j-i}{\sqrt2}
$$
which is absurd.
